# Prove that a sequence is a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a recursively defined sequence with

[image] and [image] for all [image].

Then a1=1/3, a2=8/27 etc. Considering that 0< x< 1/3 and 0< x^2< 1/9 and thus 8/9< 1-x^2< 1 and thereby 8/27< (1-x^2)/3< 1/3 we get:

[image]

Induction yields that each following an is element of the interval (0,1/3) and for all n>=3

[image]

and thus

[image]

and generally

[image]

which yields a geometric sum whose result ultimately proves that the sequence is a Cauchy sequence. My problem is the 2/9. Where does it come from?

Comment: $\frac{|a_n| + |a_{n-1}|}{3} = \frac{1}{3}(|a_n| + |a_{n-1}|) < \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{2}{9}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just applying $|a_{n-1}|,\,|a_n|\,< 1/3$:

$$\frac{|a_n|+|a_{n-1}|}3\ <\  \frac{1/3+1/3}3\ =\frac{2/3}3=\frac29\,.$$